# Want to get drop down value on php sql query without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, sql

How to put drop down value in sql query?

I used cache to solve this but after refresh the particular div the inner functionality is not working (ajax call)

```
 <section>
         <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select Operators Name
                        </label>
                        <select class="form-control col col-6" id="op_name" name="op_id">
                       <?php //to select operator
$customer_mast = mysqli_query($con1, "SELECT * FROM `tbloperator`");
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($customer_mast)) {?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row2['op_id'] ?>">
                            <?php echo $row2['name']; ?>
                          </option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select> 
                      </section> 
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblpacktypemaster` WHERE `broadcaster_id` = 0 AND `operator_id`=".$dropdownvalue."";
 mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

....Nos of lines for pack, long duration price period depend on query using while loop. and all other is coming from ajax call.

Comment: We can't give you an answer without seeing your code

Comment: use ajax or fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "fetchlist.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        // Here, you may bind response with your select HTML
    }
});
```

You may either return json from your php file and create DOM elements in response. Or, you may create HTML version and return as response. Suggestion will be to use `JSON` for better flexibility.